# Sum from select less or equal than

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries:

```sql
SELECT
    Customer,
    MAX(Week) AS MaxWeek
FROM
    Uploads
WHERE
    year = 2022
GROUP BY
    Customer;
```

| Customer | MaxWeek |
| --- | --- |
| CustomerA | 6 |
| CustomerB | 7 |
| CustomerC | 6 |

```sql
SELECT
    Customer,
    SUM(SoldUnits) AS TotalSold2021
FROM
    Uploads
WHERE
    year = 2021
GROUP BY
    Customer;
```

| Customer | TotalSold2021 |
| --- | --- |
| CustomerA | 168 |
| CustomerB | 457 |
| CustomerC | 289 |

The second query returns me all of the sales of 2021 but I want just until the max week of every customer.

I tried this:

```sql
SELECT
    Customer,
    Week,
    SUM(SoldUnits) AS TotalSold2021
FROM
    Uploads
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
         Customer AS Customer,
         MAX(Week) AS MaxWeek
     FROM 
         Uploads
     WHERE
         year = 2022
     GROUP BY
         Customer) T1 ON T1.Customer = Customer
                      AND T1.MaxWeek = Week
WHERE
    year = 2021
GROUP BY
    Customer;
```

| Customer | Week | TotalSold2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CustomerA | 6 | 11 |
| CustomerB | 7 | 19 |
| CustomerC | 6 | 21 |

But the sum is only of the week and I want from week 1 until the max week.

Comment: Provide sample data which produces shown outout. As textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: Please show some sample data *before* any aggregation. Then show us the expected results using that sample.

Answer (score 0):

Move week test to where

```
on
  T1.Customer = Customer
where year = 2021 and week <= T1.MaxWeek
```